# I need to trigger an resize after the calculation of contentDocument.body.firstChild.offsetHeight, how?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Scenario:

- The iframe have no `src`-attribute
- the iframe get its content from javascript using setting its `contentDocument.body.innerHTML`
- The iframe has a parent element that have the style `display: none` until the user do an action.
  (The script is a plugin, so have limited access to its parent elements that sometimes have `display:none`)

Solved so far:

- Wrapping the content inside a div, to use the height of that div as reference, so setting height to a padding-value + `body.firstChild.offsetHeight`
- Trigger a resize a few miliseconds after the content is set
- Trigger a resize on windows-resize
- Don't trigger a resize on load, as a iframe without src is firing loaded before the content is set.

Problem:

- When the iframe is not visible (a parent element has `display: none`), the `contentDocument.body.firstChild.offsetHeight` is zero (tested in firefox), (same with `contentDocument.body.scrollHeight`)
- Need to trigger an resize after the calculation of `contentDocument.body.firstChild.offsetHeight`

Can I use some kind of event listener to notice when the `contentDocument.body.firstChild.offsetHeight` is calculated?

(If possible I want to avoid to use `setInterval()`)